# Can't call constructor of inner class in a static context -- "non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context"

Tags: java, compiler-errors, static, this, non-static

I have an `OuterClass` and an `NestedClass`. Like this.

```java
public class OuterClass
{

        public class NestedClass
        {



        }

}
```

Whenever I try to call the constructor of `NestedClass` in a static context (like as a static field or a static method), I get a compiler error.

Here is an example code.

```java
public class OuterClass
{

        public class NestedClass
        {

                public static final NestedClass someStaticField = new NestedClass();

                public static NestedClass someStaticMethod()
                {

                        return new NestedClass();

                }

        }

}
```

And here are the compiler errors that I get.

```
$ javac OuterClass.java
OuterClass.java:7: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
                public static final NestedClass someStaticField = new NestedClass();
                                                                 ^
OuterClass.java:12: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
                        return new NestedClass();
                               ^
2 errors
```

What do these errors mean, and what should I be writing instead to achieve the desired outcome of being able to call the constructor in a static context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `NestedClass` is not `static` - neither implicitly nor explicitly declared as such - so it is an *inner class*. From Java Language Specification [8.1.3. Inner Classes and Enclosing Instances](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3):

> An *inner* class is a nested class that is not explicitly or implicitly `static`.

To create an instance of such inner class, an instance of the enclosing (outer class) is needed. If **not** in a static context, `this` is implicitly used when creating such an instance. In a static context, there is no `this` and we must provide the instance of the enclosing class. This is accomplish by using a *qualified* class instance creation expression like:

> `outer.new InnerClass()`

as described in [JLS 15.9. Class Instance Creation Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9-400-B.1):

> A qualified class instance creation expression enables the creation of instances of inner member classes and their anonymous subclasses.

More details can be found in [JLS 15.9.2. Determining Enclosing Instances](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.2).

---

Applying that to the code of the question, we could do:

```
public class OuterClass
{

    public class NestedClass // actually an Inner Class
    {
        public static final NestedClass someStaticField = new OuterClass().new NestedClass();

        public static NestedClass someStaticMethod()
        {
            var outer = new OuterClass();
            return outer.new NestedClass();
        }
    }
}
```

A second possibility would be to not make the nested class an inner class by declaring it as `static` and avoiding the need for an enclosing instance:

```
public class OuterClass
{

    // static added to following declaration
    public static class NestedClass
    {
        public static final NestedClass someStaticField = new NestedClass();

        public static NestedClass someStaticMethod()
        {
            return new NestedClass();
        }
    }
}
```

Which solution to use should be based on the specific use case and data model, not just because the compiler accepts it!

---

Note: `static` members of inner classes are allowed since Java 16 ([JEP 359](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395#Static-members-of-inner-classes)), so we can have record classes, which are `static`, declared in inner classes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I see now how there always was a way to accomplish this, but I see now that they allowed even more.

Answer (score -3):

Long story short, the problem is because, in Java, if my `NestedClass` does not have a `static` modifier up front, then it is considered an ***Inner Class***, and ***Inner Classes are not allowed to have static fields or methods***. So, if I want my `NestedClass` to have static fields or methods, then I must make my `NestedClass` a ***Static Nested Class***. Meaning, I need to put a `static` modifier in front of the `class` on my `NestedClass`.

Here is the change.

```
BEFORE -- public class NestedClass
AFTER  -- public static class NestedClass
```

---

And for the long version, here is a great tutorial by Oracle themselves that walks you through the concept.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

In short, if there is a class `B` that is inside of class `A`, then class `B` is considered a ***Nested Class***.

There are 2 types of ***Nested Classes*** -- ***Inner Classes*** and ***Static Nested Classes***.

***Inner Classes*** are when the class is defined the way I did above -- one class inside of another. In the immediate example, class `B` would NOT have a static modifier in front of it.

***Static Nested Classes*** are the exact same as ***Inner Classes***, but they DO have a static modifier in front of it.

So for example.

```java
public class OuterClass
{

        //    not static!
        public class InnerClass
        {

                public static final InnerClass someStaticField = new InnerClass();

                public static InnerClass someStaticMethod()
                {

                        return new InnerClass();

                }

        }
        
        //     static! -- If you don't put the static keyword, then it's not a static class!
        public static class StaticNestedClass
        {

                public static final StaticNestedClass someStaticField = new StaticNestedClass();

                public static StaticNestedClass someStaticMethod()
                {

                        return new StaticNestedClass();

                }


        }

}
```

If I try to compile this, my `InnerClass` gets the same 2 compilation errors (like in my question), but my `StaticNestedClass` gets NO COMPILATION ERRORS!

The reason for this is that ***Static Nested Classes are allowed to have static fields/methods, but Inner Classes are not allowed to have static fields/methods***.

This is a strict rule. That means, the only way I can possibly get my `NestedClass` to have a static field or method is by turning that ***Inner Class*** into a ***Static Nested Class***, and that is done by putting the `static` keyword in front of the `class` keyword.

Here is the fixed version.

```java
public class OuterClass
{

        //now its static!
        public static class NestedClass
        {

                public static final NestedClass someStaticField = new NestedClass();

                public static NestedClass someStaticMethod()
                {

                        return new NestedClass();

                }

        }

}
```

No more compilation errors!

Comment: "Inner Classes are not allowed to have static fields or methods." This is totally wrong... Did you even try that? Also, to create your instance you can write `public static Inner instance = new Outer().new Inner()`.

Comment: this answer is wrong - see Java Language Specification [8.1.3. Inner Classes and Enclosing Instances](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3-130): "*In particular, an inner class may declare and inherit static members (§8.2), and declare static initializers (§8.7), even though the inner class itself is not static.*" (the restriction was *relaxed* in Java 16 - [JEP 395](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395))

Comment: Hey folks, thanks for the correction. To answer your question @AlexR I absolutely did try, I cycled through several different permutations. But I didn't try that one. Either way, my main mistake was not verifying my logic against the JLS. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: And thank you for the notice @user16320675 I guess more ways to accomplish this have recently popped up